# Increase php session time

Tags: php, session

I am trying to increase my php session time to 6 hours.

Here is the code to increase the session time:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 6); // 6 Hours
```

However, it seems to ONLY have a session time of 1 hour.

Any suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Also, how do I test this feature without having to wait 6 hours to see if my session times out.

Comment: is `ini_set` allowed on your system? Are you calling it before `session_start()`?

Comment: what does the entry for `session.gc_maxlifetime` say when you do a `phpinfo();` on the same page after your `ini_set()` ?

Comment: I want to create the session timeout to 6 hours but my browser is timing out in 1/2 hour.  I am on a PLESK server.

I updated .htaccess to have the settings:
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 21600
php_value session.cache_expire 21600
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 21600

Here is the relevant PHPinfo:
session.gc_maxlifetime local=21600 master=1440
session.cache_expire local=21600 master=180
session.gc_maxlifetime local=21600 master=1440

Comment: - For sharing hosting providers check = https://stackoverflow.com/a/58465785/8010015

Answer (score 15):

**The scenario**

You’re running Debian Linux or Ubuntu Linux. You want PHP sessions to last longer than the default 1440 seconds (24 minutes). So you do this:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 10800);    # 3 hours
```

With this setting, sessions should remain active for at least three hours, as long as users don’t close their browser.1

But no matter what you do, sessions keep getting deleted after 24–54 minutes. It seems PHP is ignoring the gc_maxlifetime setting.

**Why this happens**

Debian and Ubuntu Linux override PHP’s session behavior. If you look closely, you’ll see that session.gc_probability is set to 0, meaning PHP’s garbage collection will never run. Instead, there’s a Debian-specific cron job in /etc/cron.d/php5 that runs every 30 minutes!

The cron job does garbage collection based on the global session.gc_maxlifetime in php.ini. The session.gc_maxlifetime in your app is ignored.

**The solution**

While you could disable the cron job and/or modify php.ini, I’d prefer to fix the problem without modifying system defaults. A better solution is to create your own sessions directory, somewhere outside the normal one, and then locally enable PHP’s session garbage collection.

**To do this**, `set session.gc_maxlifetime, session.gc_probability, session.gc_divisor, and session.save_path`:

```
# Session lifetime of 3 hours
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 10800);

# Enable session garbage collection with a 1% chance of
# running on each session_start()
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);

# Our own session save path; it must be outside the
# default system save path so Debian's cron job doesn't
# try to clean it up. The web server daemon must have
# read/write permissions to this directory.
session_save_path(APP_PARENT_DIR . '/sessions');

# Start the session
session_start();
```

Comment: This answer appears to be copied from this blog post: http://natesilva.tumblr.com/post/250569350/php-sessions-timeout-too-soon-no-matter-how-you. Are you the author of the blog, or did you just find it and copy the relevant information?

Answer (score 2):

Increasing session.gc_maxlifetime via ini_set may not work if there is another script that runs (e.g. an other vhost) that uses the same session.save_path. The other script removes the sessions of all scripts by its own lifetime:

> **Note:**
>   If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Also be sure to change the setting before session_start(). If you have session.auto_start enabled, it is to late when you use ini_set.

Answer (score 0):

Lemp/LAMP (Ubuntu)  I solve my issue

Edit: `sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`

gc_maxlifetime 1440 to any big number

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 144000
```

Answer (score 0):

In most common cases you need to edit `/etc/php.ini` and change this (for 6 hours):

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 216000
```

Recently I came across a Rocky Linux 9 installation with PHP 8.x and it reflected the new `session.gc_maxlifetime` in `phpinfo()` **only after I rebooted the server**. Not after I restarted `httpd` web server service.

For debugging you can also create a PHP page and write `<?php phpinfo();?>` in it, it will show you the current `session.gc_maxlifetime` but also all the loaded `.ini` configuration files, wich might overwrite your value.

Answer (score -2):

> Try following-

- **Avoid spaces**

> ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*6);
>
> Or

- **simply enter values into seconds as...**

> ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 21600);

Comment: The spaces don't matter, nor do you have to manually multiply the values.  Why does this question seem to be attracting such responses?

Answer (score -23):

use this

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6 * 60 * 60); // 6 Hours  instead to this 
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 6); // 1 Hours 
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', [hours] * [minutes] * [seconds]);
```

Comment: That's simply not correct.  The order of multiplication does not matter.

Comment: thats just the worst answer i've ever seen ;)