# Session get destroyed before authTimeout expire in yii2

Tags: php, session, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

In Yii2,I have in my config/main.php

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'authTimeout' => 43200,
        'loginUrl' => null,
    ],
...
]
```

when i am trying to see my authTimeout variable in my whole system is ok and everything works fine except my session get expire before authTimeout.I am using access_token for login because my frontend is angular and also using mdmsoft/yii2-admin for RBAC.
And i am not getting,why i am logging out before my authTimeout?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because globally, `session.gc_maxlifetime` is set to be lower than what you have set in your application.  You can use `echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");` to get the current value.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023106/1437261) discusses how to increase that within your application. Note, that some hosts tend to override the session timeout value set in php.ini, as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238136/increase-php-session-time). Even if that is the case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023131/1437261) would help.

If this is not the case, then please provide more information about your script, host and php configuration. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: my session.gc_maxlifetime is 1440 which means 24 minutes but i am logged out not in specific time.I have something like timer running everytime when i click some activity.Sometime i see i was not logged out in 4 hours also some time in 1 hours.I see my authTime out inside my application is same as i have in config.When i go to my yii2soft inside web to User.php i have duration is 216000.If i see my Expire time is browser is also after 12 hours.Is it possible like in my every request my session.gc_maxlifetime will be add to my previous session(ie.session.gc_maxlifetime)?